# Change a string in one class from another class. Android

Tags: java, android, string, class

So I'm trying to change the value of a string (it's called "string1") in the class Favoutires.

I'm using the below code.
Any ideas why it's not working and maybe what will work?

```
String Athenry = "Athenry";

                Favourites favourites = new Favourites();
                favourites.string1 = Athenry;
```

Below is my Favorites Class

```
public class Favourites extends ActionBarActivity {

    String string1;
    String st2;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fav);
        final Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: Can you expand in what way it's not working? Does the value not change? Do you get an error?
(On a separate note, it's convention to give variables camelCase names so ``Athenry`` would be ``athenry`` so that it's not confused with a class which have TitleCase names.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to make the String string1 static

```
public class Favourites extends ActionBarActivity {

 public static  String string1;
String st2;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fav);
    final Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and

```
Favourites.string1 = Athenry;
```

Comment: But then every ``Favourites`` will have the same value for string1.

Comment: @Moubeen Farooq Warar :  Thank you so much. I've been programming in Python lately so I'm gonna blame that as my over sight. haha Thanks again, you're a legend.

Comment: Favourites.string1 = Athenry; this will change the valie for string1 and when you will try to access string1 it will return Athenry

Comment: ``Favourites f1 = new Favourites();
f1.string1 = "Athenry";
Favourites f2 = new Favourites();
f2.string1 = "Not Athenry";
// f1.string1 now equals "Not Athenry"``

Answer (score 2):

Because you did declare the access modifier for the variable string1. It is private by default. You have to make it public like this:

```
public String string1;
```

But that is a bad practice. You would want to have getter and setters for these kinds of jobs. So basically this:

```
private String string1;
public String setString1(String s){
string1 = s;
}
```

And you access it by calling the method

```
Object.setString("Your String");
```

Answer (score 0):

you chould make a setter for that string

```
public class Favourites extends ActionBarActivity {
String string1;
public void setString1(String value){
      string1=value;
}
```

and then call it when you need

```
String Athenry = "Athenry";

            Favourites favourites = new Favourites();
            favourites.setString1(Athenry);
```